# Ionic 4 loading symbol dismisses before observable resolves

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4

I have few asynchronous tasks that run before navigating to the home screen. I am initiating a loading spinner before these tasks are initiated and closing the loading spinner inside ionViewWillLeave() method.

My expectation is that the loading spinner keeps on loading as these asynchronous tasks finish their execution and once these are done the loading spinner should only be dismissed from ionViewWillLeave method.

My current code looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
      ngOnInit(){}
      buttonClicked(){
         this.ionLoadingService.present();
         zip(Obs1, Obs2).pipe(switchMap(()=>Obs3))
                        .subscribe(()=>{navigate('/app/home')});
      }
      ionViewWillLeave(){
        this.ionLoadingService.dismiss();
      }
}
export class IonLoadingService {

   public loadingElement: HTMLIonLoadingElement;
   private loaderPresented: boolean = false;
   constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) {
   }

   async present() {
     if (!this.loaderPresented) {
       this.loaderPresented = true;
       this.loadingElement = await this.loadingController.create({
         cssClass: 'custom-loading'
      });
     return await this.loadingElement.present();
   }
 }
```

Note: All the observables are API calls which run outside angular zone.
The current behavior of loading spinner is it disappears once these outer observable starts executing.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: could you show us the code where you initiate the spinner? Specifically where you call `create`.

Comment: @alexortizl updated IonLoadingService where I am creating/initiating the spinner